# Type bound is not inferred via constructor when using a Class parameter?

Tags: java, generics, type-inference

Trying to understand why Java behaves differently in inferring the type and checking the type bounds when passing in type information using Class parameter.

With this code as an example:

```
public class TypeTest<T extends Number> {
    Class<T> type;

    TypeTest(Class<T> type) { this.type = type; }

    static <S extends Number> void sMethod(Class<S> type) {}

    <S extends Number>  void method(Class<S> type) {}


    public static void main(String[] args) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        // 1.
        TypeTest<Integer> obj = new TypeTest(Object.class);  // compiles, unchecked call and assignment warnings

        // 2.
        obj.method(Object.class); // compile-time error, S not within bound 

        TypeTest obj1 = new TypeTest(Object.class);  // compiles, unchecked call and assignment warnings

        // 3.
        obj1.method(Object.class); // compiles, unchecked call warning .             

        // 4.
        TypeTest.sMethod(Object.class); // compile time error, Object not within bounds

        // 5.
        new TypeTest<Object>(Object.class); // compile time error, Object not within bounds
    }

}
```

With static method (4.) we cannot pass in anything that is not a Number which seems the most natural behavior with the bounds provided.

However with a constructor (1., 5.) we have to specify the type parameter explicitely to get the same behavior as 4. Otherwise it seems T type parameter value is not inferred automatically from the Object.class variable.

Where does this difference comes from for constructor and static methods?

Another case which I do not understand completely is the difference between 2. and 3. Why the same operation compiles or does not compile only depending on the way of construction of the TypeTest object, while class type parameter T has no relation whatsoever to the method type parameter S?

Comment: Without reading your question, did you with "Java 6" imply that this problem is not present in Java 5 and Java 7? If not, please remove "Java 6" from the title and the question.

Comment: No just that I have not tested this with Java 7 where some inference logic was changed. You're right it is misleading though. Will remove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you omit a type parameter for a generic type -- that is, any time you type `TypeTest` without a `<Something>` -- Java ignores *all* generic checking for *all* of that type.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html for details.

Comment: but if I change the constructor to TypeTest(T value), leaving the class definition as class TypeTest<T extends Number>, then it will fail on new TypeTest("string")

Comment: got it, the raw type has constructor TypeTest(String value) in this case but in the other case TypeTest(Class type)

Answer (score 1):

`new TypeTest(Object.class)` is an expression of the raw type `TypeTest`, that's how it is designed. So of course, no type inference is done as there **is no type to infer**.

Comment: "that's how it is designed" -- is there a reason for this, or this is just an omission? As during compile time the compiler knows that Object.class is of type Class<Object> which is not Class<T extends Number>, so why is this check not performed?

Comment: One of the reasons is that there had to be a syntax to declare a raw type. This is the most sensible syntax for that. In Java 7 you have the diamond operator and it is a much more interesting question why and how exactly `TypeTest<Integer> tt = new TypeTest<>(Object.class)` fails. To that I don't have a ready answer.

Answer (score 1):

Only generic types declared for a method or constructor can be inferred. So

```
<S> void method() {}
 ^ this can be inferred

<S> TypeTest() {}
 ^ this can be inferred
```

The generic type of a generic class cannot be inferred when constructing it:

```
class TypeTest<T> {}
               ^ this must be specified explicitly when using "new TypeTest"
                 or in Java 7 you can explicitly specify the diamond operator
```

As others have mentioned, when you use `new TypeTest()` without any angle brackets, you are using a raw type. Raw types must work the same way that they worked prior to Generics, to preserve compatibility with old code. So the expression `new TypeTest()` will have type `TypeTest` (the raw type), not `TypeTest<something>`.